# webpack4 lodash size too big

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, lodash

I'm building a small app using React, Redux and Webpack. As I've switched to Webpack v.4 I started getting warnings about bundle size. I read about ways to make it smaller. I also installed bundle analyzer and saw that I have big lodash in node-modules. As usually I'm using just one or two methods from lodash per file I changed all my imports from

`import _ from 'loadash'`

to

`import get from 'lodash/get'`

But it didn't help me to lower bundle size. Below I enclose my webpack.config.js. I have no idea why it's not working. What's even more surprising is that my build command is `webpack --mode production` and accordion to what I read in webpack 4 documentation it should have some optimization enabled `out of the box`.

webpack.config.js

```
const LodashModuleReplacementPlugin = require('lodash-webpack-plugin');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

const webpack = require('webpack');

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: ['babel-polyfill', './src/index.js']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: ".",
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        inline: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        port: 8880
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
                            plugins: ["transform-class-properties"]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'eslint-loader'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {}
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /^.*\.(css|scss)$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader?importLoaders=1&modules&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            plugins: () => [
                                require('autoprefixer')({
                                    browsers: ['last 1 version']
                                })
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    'sass-loader'
                ],
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new LodashModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
    ]
};
```

Dependencies and dev dependencies.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.17",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "node-sass": "^4.6.0",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.6",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-icons": "^2.2.5",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "^4.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-select": "^1.0.0-rc.10",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.4.1",
    "react-textfit": "^1.0.1",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.2.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2",
    "redux-form": "^7.1.0",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.0",
    "reselect": "^3.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.13.1"   },   "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.6",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.2.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-15": "^1.0.5",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.2.2",
    "eslint": "^5.3.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "hoist-non-react-statics": "^3.0.1",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jest": "^23.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "lodash-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.5",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "prettier": "^1.14.2",
    "transform-runtime": "^0.0.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.16.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.1"   },
```

[image: bundle analyze result as a picture]

Comment: Are you using webpack 4?

Comment: also use bundle-analyzer to see what is going big. It could not be lodash

Comment: @PlayMa256 I am using bundle-analyzer, I added my result to my post.

Comment: Can you try change you package json to :

   "lodash.**": "^4.5.0",
   "lodash.**": "^4.3.0",
   "lodash.***": "^4.4.0",

instead of "lodash": "^4.17.10",

Answer (score 1):

I recommend import only the piece/function that you need:

```
import isEmpty from 'lodash.isempty';
```

and in your package.json

```
"dependencies": {
   ...
   "lodash.foreach": "^4.5.0",
   "lodash.includes": "^4.3.0",
   "lodash.isempty": "^4.4.0",
```

Comment: This is not needed since Webpack 4 now correctly does tree shaking and lodash provides support for it to do so.

Comment: if you do import _ from 'loadash' Webpack assumed you need to use the all package and import only the deps that you need make your package more imperative

Comment: He don't do that he has the full import in his package.json

Comment: That doesn’t matter as long as you import specific parts, like `lodash/get`. Tree shaking will take care of rest.

Answer (score 1):

Lodash bundles can easily get much larger than you would expect, even from importing a single function. For example, importing only `get()` from lodash will contribute 5K to your production, minified bundle. I created a library that makes a few simplifying assumptions to provide much smaller implementations of many functions: [`micro-dash`](https://github.com/simontonsoftware/micro-dash). It's implementation of [`get()`](https://simontonsoftware.github.io/micro-dash/typedoc/index.html#get) contributes only 65 bytes. Check it out to see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Production mode by default does minification but seems you didn't defined mode in config.

For using production mode, you have to define mode like:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  mode: 'production'
  ...
};
```

**OR**

You need to pass argument in cli like:

```
webpack --mode=production
```

You are using missing `=` between `--mode` & `production`. Also default mode is again production if not provided.

Also instead of using plugin for analyzing, compression, and other utilities there are in-built support instead of using plugin [`stats`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/) can be used for analyzing.

For more details refer:

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/

Comment: thank you but even after changing to webpack --mode=production my bundle.js size is exactly the same.

Comment: How much size exactly lodash is taking after minification or emitting by webpack?

Comment: it's over 800kB